# How make curried getter function typesafe with TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to write types for the following function

```
function get(prop) {
  return (obj) => obj[prop];
}
```

I initially tried to use `keyof` but I couldn't get it to work. Now I've got this:

```
function get<K extends string>(prop: K) {
  return <V, T extends {K: V}>(obj: {K: V}) => obj[prop];
}
```

But it gives the error

```
error TS2536: Type 'K' cannot be used to index type '{ K: V; }'.
```

which seem a bit silly since `{K: V}` seems to have a key `K`.

Is it possible to make the function typesafe so that the first argument has to be a string and the argument to the returned function has to be an object with the correct property?

---

Update: Thanks for the answers. But there is, however, a problem with both solutions. Consider the code below:

```
function get<K extends string>(prop: K) {
  return <V, Obj extends Record<K, V>>(obj: Obj): Obj[K] => obj[prop];
}
const a = get("foo")({ foo: 1 });
a + 12;
```

The last line results in an error because TypeScript deduces the type `{}` for `a`. This makes the function very cumbersome to use because one will have to cast the `{}`.

Comment: Have you tried `{ [key: K]: V }`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to work with a nightly build at least:

```
function get<K extends string>(prop: K) {
  return <V, Obj extends Record<K, V>>(obj: Obj) => obj[prop];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. There is a problem however. See my edit.

Comment: Which version of TS do you use ?

Comment: I suppose they fixed that recently :(
it is correctly inferred with  2.2.0-dev.20161221

Comment: @AlexG Can you give an example of code that performs the arithmetic taht the OP shows and that won't result in an error in 2.2.0-dev.20161221? When I try it, I get the same error that the OP has reported.

Comment: @Louis Strange it compiles here. Are you sure it's not just the IDE ?

https://gist.github.com/AlexGalays/d6d1793d14490b31a55d3a7eb8ff80d3

Comment: @AlexG Yeah, I confirm that it works fine with both the version you mentioned and the current dev. (2.2.0-dev.20170111). The problem was not the IDE. It's just that if `tsc` is installed globally and locally, the global one wins. Many of the tools I use (e.g. `gulp`) perform a check to see if there is a local installation and will hand over execution to the local installation *even if there is a global installation*. I forgot that `tsc` does not do that. :-/

Comment: You're right @AlexG it has been fixed post 2.1.  Time to live on typescript@next again :) Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

What AlexG has [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41577915/1906307) does work. You can also just do it without `Record`. Here's code that illustrates both. `get` uses `Record<K, V>` whereas `get2` uses `{[x in K]: V}`.

```
function get<K extends string>(prop: K) {
  return <V, Obj extends Record<K, V>>(obj: Obj) => obj[prop];
}

function get2<K extends string>(prop: K) {
  return <V, T extends {[x in K]: V}>(obj: T) => obj[prop];
}

const foo = {
  "a": 1,
  "b": 2,
};

console.log(get("b")(foo));
console.log(get2("b")(foo));
// This line should compile fine in recent development versions and
// presumably will work fine in regular releases from 2.2.0 onwards.
// There's a bug in 2.1.x that causes the type inference to bork and 
// cause the compiler to think were adding 1 to a plain object (`{}`).
console.log(get2("b")(foo) + 1);
```

I figured the above and then though that with `get2` I'm probably just replicating what `Record` does, and [lo and behold](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/4086bd13c7b459ab4302c48fc3ac428cc2078e08/lib/lib.d.ts#L1403), that's the case because `Record` is defined like this:

```
/**
 * Construct a type with a set of properties K of type T
 */
type Record<K extends string, T> = {
    [P in K]: T;
}
```

The type inference problem you mentioned in your update is a bug in TypeScript that has been fixed in relatively recent versions of TypeScript. ([Alex mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41577501/how-make-curried-getter-function-typesafe-with-typescript/41577915?noredirect=1#comment70384650_41577915) version 2.2.0-dev.20161221. I've tried with newer versions and also got a flawless compilation.) Presumably, it will be fixed in version 2.2.0. I don't know of any solution that will fix the compilation error in versions prior to 2.2.0 and won't have *other* negative side-effects.

Comment: Actually Record is found in the standard typescript typings (lib.d.ts) since 2.1.4

Comment: Yes, I have a link to the source code in my answer. I don't know what point you are making there.

Comment: You're right; didn't read properly :)  So your answer is more complete in case he didn't switch to 2.1 yet.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. There is a problem however. See my edit.